# Continue running the program as long as inputs are valid

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

So I just started to learn to program and was working on a simple program that scans and stores the user input value as long as its a valid float. If the input is invalid, then the program immediately exits with return 1. Finally, the program will output the stored value if all of the inputs are valid. I was thinking of a structure like

```
while (scanf("%f",input)==1){
    //code that store the value of input;
    value=input
}
else{
    printf("invalid");
    return 1
}
printf("%f",value);
```

But the thing is there does not exist a While-else structure, and I really struggle to get around this. Is there any other conditioning I can do on the input do generate the desired result?

By the way, I think simply deleting the else doesn't really work-- because to output value, I must use Ctrl d to manually exit the while loop. Then because I exited while loop I will print invalid no matter what. Does there exist a structure that will only print the value? Thanks.

Comment: Just get rid of the 'else'.

Comment: Um but the thing is if I remove the else, the "invalid" will be printed and I dont want that to happen. Is there a way to avoid printing "invalid" if every input is a float?

Comment: Good job **checking the return** of your input function. If you want to output all values only if all values were valid, then you will need to change your loop structure to loop continually, and within the loop save the return from `scanf` and check against `1` (good input, store value in array), `0` (bad input, exit) or `EOF` (all inputs were good, `break` continual loop), then  loop over array outputting all values.

Answer (score 0):

a `while` loop will continue to run forever until the exit condition is reached, this means that an `else` isn't needed because the code below it isn't going to be executed.

A simple fix to this would just be removing the `else` because it is not needed :)

Comment: oh so all inputs are valid then the printf will not be executed? That makes sense thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `while` predicate has to be false for it to go on, so the hypothetical `while-else` is the same as `while`. One wants to decide between (at least) three outcomes from `sscanf`:

- completed processing a float;
- error processing, (this can be an underlying stream error or a syntax error);
- end-of-file, (of `stdin`.)

From the [sscanf documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html), one could use this set-up,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float input, value;
    int nread;
    while((nread = scanf(" %f", &input)) == 1) {
        ////code that store the value of input;
        value=input;
    }
    if(ferror(stdin)) {
        // nread != 1 && ferror: error reading input.
        perror("stdin"); // POSIX.1-2017 guarantees this will be set, not C99.
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else if(nread != EOF) {
        // nread != 1 && nread != EOF && !ferror: matching error.
        fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // nread == EOF && !ferror: normal, input ends before the first conversion has
    // completed, and without a matching failure.
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The return value from `sscanf` contains more information then just a binary decision, so in general, one wants to save it.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your code is in one function and you want to return from there when input is wrong so in that case This Will Work

```
while(1) {
    //code that store the value of input;
    if (scanf("%f",input)==1){
      value=input
    }
    else{
      return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: um but wont this always result in return 1? Because after I enter one input and the while loop scans it, the while 1 loop will continue to run, and because it doesn't scan any more inputs it will return 1